# sqlite database upgrade for multiple databases

Tags: sqlite, upgrade

I am working on a collection of 'saying' applications. There is an option to change language.
So I am using 3 sqlite database's for 3 different languages and the user can mark their favorites.

Now suppose I have version 1 uploaded to the market. If I add some more data in all 3 databases(add no new column only new data added) and upload version 2 in the market. User install the new version.

How can I keep the user favorites data from the old version of the db and add the new data of version 2 as well? Remember I have not changed the database structure or schema, I have only added some new rows.

Comment: please give more info. I'm assuming this is an android application?

Comment: Oh i am sorry to mention that. Yes this is an android application.

Comment: guys i am really need of any help....:(